# Explain whether X and Y are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, independence

Question: Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have a discrete joint distribution for which the joint probability function is defined as follows:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{30}(x+y)$$

for $x=0,1,2$ and $y=0,1,2,3$.

Determine the marginal probability functions of $X$ and $Y$ and explain whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Are my answers right for the first part?

Answers: [image]

How can I know if x and y are independent, I know that if they are independent, $f(x,y)=f_x (x) f_y (y)$, but how can I continue from here?

Comment: It's not correct. $X,Y$ are discrete random variables.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answers, am I correct now?